# Other ways of conveying the idea of building/making a snowman

Tags: word-choice

It is conventional to impart the idea of creating a snowman with the verbs "to make" or "to build".

Would it be expedient to use for the same purpose verbs applicable to the volumetric objects from the sphere of art, such as:

1. to sculpt/sculpture a snowman
2. to mould a snowman
3. to model a snowman
4. to form a snowman
5. to carve/chisel a snowman?

Answer (score 6):

An *artist* might indeed use any of those techniques to create a snowman, but *children* only make them or build them.

To carve or chisel a snowman - and probably to sculpt one - you would need a block of ice, not just heaps of snow. To mould one I guess you'd need a mould.

We wouldn't use 'form' here, unless we were encountering a snowman for the first time: 'A man formed entirely from snow!'

We don't use *model*. Neither do we use *create* or *construct*, though [Jacob Rees-Mogg](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/04/world/europe/rees-mogg-slouching-brexit.html) may well say, "Look, children! Daddy's fashioned a snowman!"

Comment: Nice. And note that there such things as snow sculptures but they are intricate and not just 3 balls of rolled snow with a carrot, sticks and coal.  https://www.wintercarnival.com/2018-vulcan-park-snow-sculpting-competition-winners/

Comment: Ah yes! Well done. I've seen them once  - Mottisfont Revels, 1995 - but had forgotten. Lovely. Yes - more intricate than our home-made ones, but we'd be in trouble if we introduced a second carrot.